# Is every $\omega\in H^0(U,\Omega_U^n)$ representable in $H^n(U,\mathbb{C})$ by an element from $H^0(X,\Omega_X^n(\log D))$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory

Let $U$ be a smooth variety, and $U\hookrightarrow X$ an smooth compactification with snc boundary $D=X\setminus U$.  Suppose that $\omega\in H^0(U,\Omega^n_U)$ is global algebraic $n$-form on $U$. It defines a class in $H^n(U,\mathbb{C})=\mathbb{H}^n(X,\Omega_X^\bullet(\log D))$.

The form $\omega$ extends to a meromorphic form on $X$, denote it by $\tilde{\omega}$. This is not necessarily an element of $H^0(X,\Omega_X^n(\log D))$, since $\tilde{\omega}$ can have poles of higher order. Is there an element $\omega'\in H^0(X,\Omega_X^n(\log D))$ such that $\omega'|_U$ defines the same cohomology class as $\omega$ in $H^n(U,\mathbb{C})$?

Here are my thoughts: the Hodge spectral sequence degenerates, and so we have
$$Gr_F^i(H^n(U,\mathbb{C}))=H^{n-i}(X,\Omega^i(\log D)),$$
and so non-canonically (I believe)
$$H^n(U,\mathbb{C})=\bigoplus_i H^{n-i}(X,\Omega^i(\log D)).$$
Now it seems that the class defined by $\omega$ should be contributed by the summand $H^{0}(X,\Omega^n(\log D))$, which would imply the claim. However, to prove this I think one would need something analogous to what Peters and Steenbrink call a "Hodge decomposition in the strong sense" (page 45). However, I do not know if this kind of result exists for non-compact $U$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true. Take for $X$ an elliptic curve, for $D$ a point $p\in X$. The restriction map $H^1(X,\mathbb{C})\rightarrow H^1(U,\mathbb{C})$ is an isomorphism, and $H^0(X,\Omega ^1_X(\log D))=H^0(X,\Omega ^1_X)$. There is a form $\tilde{\omega } $ with a pole of order 2 at $p$; its restriction $\omega $ to $U$ is not cohomologous to the restriction of a  holomorphic form on $X$.

Comment: Do you know if there is a sense in which we can associate to this $\tilde{\omega}$ its "part" lying in $H^0(X,\Omega_X^1(\log D))$? So is there a canonical projection $H^1(U,\mathbb{C})\to H^0(X,\Omega_X^1(\log D))$ and $H^1(U,\mathbb{C})\to H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$?

Comment: No, there is no  canonical projection from $H^1(U,\mathbb{C})$ to $H^0(X,\Omega ^1_X(\log D))$ — it goes the other way around. There is indeed a canonical map $H^1(U,\mathbb{C})\rightarrow H^1(X,\mathscr{O}_X)$, induced by the morphism of complexes $\Omega ^{\scriptstyle\bullet}_X(\log D)\rightarrow \mathscr{O}_X$.

Comment: But isn't (in your example) $H^1(U,\mathbb{C})$ a pure mixed hodge structure of weight $1$? And $V^{1,0}=F^1H^1(U,\mathbb{C})=H^0(X,\Omega_X^1(\log D))$. Then $V^{0,1}=\overline{H^0(X,\Omega_X^1(\log D))}$, and the splitting $H^1(U,\mathbb{C})=V^{0,1}\oplus V^{1,0}$ should give a projection right?

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry — I was considering the general case. In the case of the example you are right.

Comment: Do you know how to describe the two components of the form you consider in your answer under this decomposition of $H^1(U,\mathbb{C})$?

Answer (score 1):

This rarely happens. For example, when $U$ is an affine smooth variety, then by Grothendieck's algebraic de Rham theorem (or degeneration of Hodge spectral sequence at $E_2$),

$$H^n(U,\mathbb C)\cong\{\alpha\in H^0(U,\Omega^n)|d\alpha=0\}/\{d\beta|\beta\in H^0(U,\Omega^{n-1})\}.$$

In other words, $H^n(U,\mathbb C)$ are represented by closed algebraic $n$-forms on $U$. So if any closed algebraic $n$-form is cohomologous to some logarithmic form, then it would imply $$H^n(U,\mathbb C)=H^0(U,\Omega_U(\log D))=F^nH^n(U,\mathbb C),$$

which is a pretty strong condition.